# I am getting no-undef when I am trying to run my react app

Tags: reactjs

When I am trying to run my react app it shows me the following error.
Earlier The code was working on a different app. But when I created a new app and trying to create any function or state it is showing it is undefined

The Code is provided below -

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App'
    
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';

class App extends React.Component {


    onSearchSubmit = (term) => {
        console.log(term)
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ui container" style={{ marginTop: '10px' }}>
                <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

SearchBar.js is

```
import React from 'react';

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    state = { term: '' };   

    onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.onSubmit(this.state.term);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ui segment">
                <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="ui form">
                    <div className="field">
                        <label>Image Search</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            onChange={e => this.setState({ term: e.target.value })}
                            value={this.state.term}
                        />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>);
    }
}

export default SearchBar;
```

The error shown is -

> Failed to compile
>
> src/components/App.js
>
> Line 7:9:  'onSearchSubmit' is not defined  no-undef
>
> src/components/SearchBar.js
>
> Line 4:5:  'state' is not defined         no-undef
>
> Line 6:5:  'onFormSubmit' is not defined  no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Let everyone understand your problem, You should be add your code

Comment: We'll be able to help only if you provide the details/implementation of the individual components where you are getting these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a constructor in your components

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           term: '' 
        };
    }
  //...
}
```

Comment: I have used this method but the error was still the same.